# TMG with client certificates for TS Gateway

Tags: terminal-server, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-ftmg-2010

How to set up client side certificate authentication using an enterprise CA for a TS gateway via Forefront TMG 2010?

To date I have executed the following:

- I have a Terminal Services Gateway configured and working in house.
- I set up a basic unauthenticated publishing rule to test that the certificates, etc are good.
- I updated this rule according to [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc995097.aspx).

At varying points I have also tried enabling / disabling the client certificates on my IIS instance, the 'require ssl client certificate' and 'require all users to authenticate' options in TMG and a couple options in the client client certificate trust list.

There have been several additional pages I've looked over as well - [2](http://4sysops.com/archives/using-tmg-one-time-passwords-and-kerberos-constrained-delegation/) and [3](http://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-use-kerberos-constrained-delegation-with-forefront-tmg/) and [4](http://blog.becker.sc/2011/07/how-to-configure-tmg-for-ssl-client.html) among many others.

EDIT - I'm specifically interested in any listener, IIS or RADIUS specific parts of the configuration but a summary of the whole would probably be beneficial to the community at large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TMG can convert a client certificate associated with a Windows user account into an authenticated (i.e. NTLM or Kerb) connection with the TSG internally.

But the TSG won't see the client certificate; client certificates work for a single hop, that's all.

So functionally, you treat TSG like any other website:

- make TMG a domain member (and ensure it trusts the issuing CA; that's "natural" for a domain member with an Ent Issuing CA installed in the forest so shouldn't require work)
- ensure the client certificates issued to client users are associated with that user in AD
- disable client certificate authentication at the website level (i.e. the TSG) and use Integrated Auth
- configure TMG to accept client certificates and forward integrated creds to the website (TSG)

Any of the Exchange (/activesync) client certificate authentication guides using ISA or TMG can be used as a template for this.

Comment: Thanks Tristan. Additionally there is a bug in the mstsc executable at current that stops CRL lookups, thus requiring an enterprise edition certificate server with an OCSP server in place.

Comment: Do you have any more details on that?

Comment: I ran across a couple vague references (mostly on experts exchange) and one half way decent description. I tested it out by adding a bogus OCSP entry to a test certificate - without it I don't see any firewall traffic or IIS logs generated. The execution dies on the client box.

Comment: So the client otherwise doesn't look up the CRL specified on the server certificate? Weird. (or is this the client cert we're discussing?)

Comment: The client does not look up the server cert. I tried generating them independently to see if the problem exists in the reverse direction. It does not (or at least this error pops up first).